# Example of continuous positive function without limit whose improper integral is convergent

Tags: improper-integrals

I would like an example of a function that is continuous and positive and has the following properties:
$$\int_a^{\infty}f(x) dx $$ is convergent and $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \not = 0$$
(I think the limit should not exist).

Comment: Take spikes of height $1$ centered at the integers whose bases have lengths tending to zero sufficiently fast. Add $e^{-x}$ to make things positive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was my idea as well, but there is no way the function can be described without "branches", right?

Comment: You could express the "spikes" as an infinite sum of compressions and translations of a "basic spike".

Comment: And how would the definition of the function look like in that case?

Comment: Let $g$ be piecewise linear  with support on $[-1,1]$, increasing on $[-1,0]$, decreasing on $[0,1]$, and  with $g(0)=1$. Then take as the spike function $h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g\bigl(n^2(x-n)\bigr)$.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: when the limit can be zero? Any idea?

Comment: This (more recent) post answers your question: [If the integral of a positive/negative function is convergent, then the limit of the function will be zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083821/if-the-integral-of-a-positive-negative-function-is-convergent-then-the-limit-of)